# Track down template errors - error is just shown in "type_traits" and doesn't give indication where to look

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, visual-studio-2015, invoke

Thanks for taking your time to look at my issue. I am currently doing a port of a quite big C++ project (a Cocos2dx game) to Windows. I received the project and was able to handle all errors except for two remaining ones which seem to be related to templates. The following errors are shown:

```
Error   C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found ...  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits    1434    
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'    ...  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits 1434
```

The source in type_traits around that line looks like this:

```
template<class _Cv_void,
    class... _Valtys> inline
    void _Invoke_ret(_Forced<_Cv_void, true>, _Valtys&&... _Vals)
    {   // INVOKE, "implicitly" converted to void
    _STD invoke(_STD forward<_Valtys>(_Vals)...);
    }
```

To be honest I am quite new to templates and haven't really used them by myself before. As far as I see it this error tells me that somewhere in my project there is a template which isn't used correctly. The problem is that there are a ton of them used and I have no clue where to start looking. Just a few examples:

```
... template<typename T>
    class Currency { ...

... template<typename AllocatedType, const unsigned int objectPerAllocation>
class BatchAllocator ...

... template<class T>
    static T selectRandomItem( ...)
```

And so on.. Is there any possibility to find out where exactly the problem is caused in the source files? I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, Platform Toolset is set to Visual Studio 2015 (v140).

Comment: it's impossible that the error messages don't show the exact line where the problem is.

Comment: Well it shows the line in the file type_traits (which is a read-only file) but that's it. I am totally confused and maybe on the wrong path at all and the error is something completely different. But searching the web for similar problems I only find people trying to implement templates and having the same issue, but when creating a new file and getting the error then it's easy to locate where it might be. But as I have this complete project I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: Maybe it also hints to a missing feature in VS2015 due to C++11/C++14 or something like that? (Similar example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078339/valid-code-fail-to-be-compiled-by-visual-studio-2015-std-function-bug)

Comment: At a minimum, you want to show the full compiler output, not the truncated version in the "error" window. `invoke` is a fairly widely used helper in the standard library; something somewhere is apparently passing it bogus arguments, but it's impossible to tell with what you've shown.